# Ways to look for changes on a PC

Tags: wifi

The other day I got the password for our school's Wifi but even though that's the case, I still can't connect. So I visited the guys at my school's IT department and they said they need to borrow my laptop so I can connect to the network. I gave it to them.

Few minutes later it was returned to me and true enough I was able to connect to the network.

But I'm very worried about what they did to my laptop. I was unable to ask them and I'm not going back there anytime soon.

If they installed something, how do I know? (No new programs listed on control panel, but I still have doubts). I'm really worried they installed something that will allow them to control my laptop.

- How do make sure nothing was installed?
- I'm thinking about using AVG antivirus to check, is it good enough?
- What do you think are the things that they have done that they hope I won't notice?

Comment: They secretly installed Skynet on your computer so it will take over the world in 10 years.

Comment: This is an educated guess.  They looked at what your MAC address is and added it to their allowed list.  If you are really worried GO ASK THEM!

Comment: It's a helpdesk.... it's not like they did anything illegal.

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately, it's near impossible to tell with absolute certainty that nothing was installed on your system.  Rootkits and such make it next to impossible to verify a system is clean after an infection which is why the adage to "nuke it from orbit" exists in the security community.

That said, you seem to be paranoid about this.  Why do you expect that they would do anything other than fix the problem?  Why would the school want to risk lawsuits if detected or the employees risk losing their jobs and quite possibly facing criminal charges in order to sneak something on to your system?

Why do you trust them any less than you trust the people who originally installed the OS on your machine (or even the firmware in your system)?  They are doing a job of trying to keep a network running smoothly and unless they've given you a reason to suspect otherwise, they are most likely trustworthy and just doing their job.